# jQuery Change parameter's event Object of a cloned element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

After I cloned a div with button inside I realized I can't (maybe) change the parameters passed to button's event.

Example:

```
var containerdiv = $('<div></div>'); //DivCreation
//. . . . . .
$(containerdiv).attr('id', 'comcreation_' + idcom);//DivCreation Attrib ID
var clonebutton = $('<button/>') //First button Clone
    .text("Clone")
    .click(({div: containerdiv, idcom: id}), function (e) {
        totcloned++;
        var newcontainer = containerdiv.clone(true);
        $('#com' + e.data.idcom, newcontainer).text("Nuovo");
        $('input[name="comid"]', newcontainer).val(-1);
        $(newcontainer).attr('id', 'comcreation_' + 'clonediv' + totcloned);
        $('body').append(newcontainer);
    });
var savebutton = $('<button/>') //Save button
    .text("Save")
    .click(({div: containerdiv}), function (e) //"div:container" is parameter i need to change in cloned div
    {
        var div = $(e.data.div);
        //Selector on div to save data
        // . . . . .
    }
//. . . . . . .
containerdiv.append(savebutt);
containerdiv.append(clonebutton);
$('body').append(containerdiv);
```

When I first click save on NOT cloned div all is correct.
When I click save on cloned div the save function get the NOT cloned div as parameters instead of the cloned one.

How do I change the "div" passed to the savebutton event to the "cloned div"?

Comment: use this, parent, child or other selectors. It would help if you [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net) it.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Hacking around the properties of an event is a very odd thing to be doing in this situation.

Comment: also you can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rSSrs/)

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
  var div = $(e.data.div);
```

to

```
  var div = $(this).parent();
```

Solved the problem!

thank you :)